# Material design sliding tabs not accessing more than two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have designed material design sliding tabs in android. I have added 3 tabs and want to change the UI at runtime from main activity but only 2 fragments has been instantiated and accessed except the 3rd. how to get the 3rd fragment to be instantiated and accessed?

Comment: Are you using viewpager? If so I'm pretty sure it only loads the current fragment, +1 to the left, and +1 to the right. So if it starts at 1, 3 won't get loaded until 2 does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `offscreenPageLimit` for the `ViewPager` is `1`. so, the `ViewPager` loads and extra one page from left and one page from right (total 3 pages).

You can change that by calling [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)
this will load a `2` pages from each side (total 5 pages).

Comment: Didn't know this. I like the limit at 1, as every time I use viewpager I'm doing lots of networking in each page. But knowing it can be adjusted is nice. Good answer sir

Comment: @jb15613 ur welcome, always read the Documentation :) @ Sundari Narayanan please accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this

[Implement Sliding Tab Layout](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)

Comment: Add full answer then use the link as a reference.